# How to redirect cygwin console output to a file

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I'm using

`$ make -f Makefile_back_With_ObjectFile > data.txt`

in **cygwin** console for redirect output to `data.txt` file, But I'm not getting all the data in that txt file, can anyone help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: What data is missing, and can you verify that this data was present before you ran the command?

Comment: is there any other command for redirect output?

Comment: you can see, what data will display on the console and what data will store in data.txt file from below :

Data on Console ::
$ make -f Makefile_back_With_ObjectFile > data.txt
/cygdrive/e/NXP/Hiren_Code/NXP_GAS_Emulator_Cygwin/Source/osal/serial.c: In function ‘signal_handler_IO’:
/cygdrive/e/NXP/Hiren_Code/NXP_GAS_Emulator_Cygwin/Source/osal/serial.c:396:19: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
          if (bufer[i] == 0x01) // Frame Start Byte
                   ^

Comment: Data in file 
cc -DDEBUG_ZCL -DDEBUG_SERIAL -DDEBUG_APPMSG -I/cygdrive/e/NXP/Hiren_Code/NXP_GAS_Emulator_Cygwin/Include -I/cygdrive/e/NXP/Hiren_Code/NXP_GAS_Emulator_Cygwin/Include/osal -I/cygdrive/e/NXP/Hiren_Code/NXP_GAS_Emulator_Cygwin/Include/services -I/cygdrive/e/NXP/Hiren_Code/NXP_GAS_Emulator_Cygwin/Include/ZSE -I/cygdrive/e/NXP/Hiren_Code/NXP_GAS_Emulator_Cygwin/NXP/Application/Common/Include -I/cygdrive/e/NXP/Hiren_Code/NXP_GAS_Emulator_Cygwin/NXP/Application/GasMeter_SE1_2-HostApp/Source -

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect also the stderr.

```
make -f Makefile_back_With_ObjectFile &> data.txt
```